# How i can get the indexes of numpy array that contain one's

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, indices

How I can get the indexes of element that contain 1 in numpy array, in an elegant way?

I tried to do a loop:

```
indexes = []
for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] == 1:
    indexes += [i]
```

Comment: np.where(array==1)

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.where`:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
np.where(a)
```

Output:

```
(array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64),)
```

Or `np.nonzero`:

```
a.nonzero()
```

Output:

```
(array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64),)
```

You can also index into `np.arange`:

```
np.arange(len(a))[a.astype(bool)]
```

Output:

```
array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: For a 1D array, you should be using `numpy.flatnonzero`

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.argwhere()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)  could be a perfect worker API for doing this. Additionally, we also have to remove the singleton dimension using [`arr.squeeze()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html). Below are two cases:

If your input is a `0-1` array, then:

```
In [101]: a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])

In [102]: np.argwhere(a).squeeze()
Out[102]: array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```

On the other hand, if you have a generic array, then:

```
In [98]: np.random.seed(23)
In [99]: arr = np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)

In [100]: arr
Out[100]: array([3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3])

In [106]: np.argwhere(arr == 1).squeeze()
Out[106]: array([2, 7])
```